# Delete child view controller in page view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Hello guys I have a problem that I've been thinking about for the past few hours. Consider the following scenario where by;

I have 3 independent `UIViewControllers` acting as child views with delete button on each view and a `UIPageViewController` to manage a simple scrollable feature for those `UIViewControllers` at the moment everything works fine with that part but I want to be able to delete view's when the delete button has been pressed.

Swift implementation would save me alot.

Comment: brother just set a new frame for this like set hight of that view 0

Comment: On delete, just navigate to the backwards `UIViewController` or forwards depending on your requirement and delete that `UIViewController` from your `dataSource`

Comment: @Rikh Please provide with examples since i'm a newbie in these stuff.